# How can I change image after every 5 second in Android

Tags: java, android, imageview

I need to change image every 5 seconds, then when we touch the `ImageView` it will stop changing until we release the touch.
When the application go to `OnPause` state it pauses the auto changing of the image.

I save the KEY_ID and stop the runnable in `onSaveInstanceState`

How can I make this change automatically ? Below is my code in java.

---

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView im_car;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    public static Integer[] mThumbeId = {R.drawable.first, R.drawable.second, R.drawable.thard};
    public int i = 0, id = 0;
    private String KEY_ID = "key_id";

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        im_car = findViewById(R.id.im_car);

        mThumbRun.run();
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            i = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_ID);
        }
        im_car.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mThumbRun);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (i!=0)
                        {
                            i = i-1;
                        }
                        else i=2;
                        mThumbRun.run();
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        if (i!=0)
        {
            i = i-1;
        }
        else i=2;
        mThumbRun.run();
    }

    Runnable mThumbRun = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            im_car.setImageResource(mThumbeId[i]);
            i++;
            if (i >= mThumbeId.length) {
                i = 0;
            }
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: add code here not in Answer

Comment: Put your code into thread and refresh it with 5 seconds ...
this may help you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a touch listener in your imageview.

Keep a boolean to check wether image should change.

```
boolean imageChangePermission = true;


yourImageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener () {
  public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
      Log.d("TouchTest", "Touch down");
    } 
    else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
      Log.d("TouchTest", "Touch up");
      imageChangePermission = false;
    }
  }
}
```

**ACTION_DOWN** - when you first touch

**ACTION_MOVE** - when you are moving your finger on screen

**ACTION_UP** - when you remove your finger from screen

Create a Handler to periodically call the change Image method of yours.

```
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(imageChangePermission) {
                changeImage();
            }
        }
    },5000); //Run after every 5 second
```